# Type Hinting Python3 How to Decorate a function based on whether its a method or a function, and transform an argument?

Tags: python, types, mypy, python-typing, pyright

Hi I'm trying to have a decorator that takes the first or second argument (depending on whether its in a class), and then transforming it before invoking the function, so the minimum code would be like this:

```py
from typing import Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar, overload, Union, cast
from inspect import ismethod

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")

class FixedClass:
  ...


class Given:
  ...

    
class Desired(Given):
  def __init__(self,):
    super().__init__()

Function = Callable[Concatenate[Desired, P], T]
TransformedFunction = Callable[Concatenate[Given, P], T]
FunctionTransformer = Callable[[Function[P, T]], TransformedFunction[P, T]]


Method = Callable[Concatenate[FixedClass, Desired, P], T]
TransformedMethod = Callable[Concatenate[FixedClass, Given, P], T]
MethodTransformer = Callable[[Method[P, T]], TransformedMethod[P, T]]


def convert_oracle(given: Given) -> Desired:
  return Desired()


def transform() -> Union[FunctionTransformer[P, T], MethodTransformer[P, T]]:

  @overload
  def command(func: Function[P, T]) -> TransformedFunction[P, T]:
    ...

  
  @overload
  def command(func: Method[P, T]) -> TransformedMethod[P, T]:
    ...

  
  
  def command(func: Union[Function[P, T], Method[P, T]]) -> Union[TransformedMethod[P, T], TransformedFunction[P, T]]:
    if ismethod(func):

      def transformed_method(self: FixedClass, given: Given, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        desired: Desired = convert_oracle(given)
        method = cast(Method[P, T], func)
        return method(self, desired, *args, **kwargs)

      return transformed_method

    def transformed_function(given: Given, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T :
      desired: Desired = convert_oracle(given)
      function = cast(Function[P, T], func)
      return function(desired, *args, **kwargs)

    return transformed_function

  return command
```

By itself like this does not raise any issues with mypy or pyright, but if I try using it, as such in these cases:

```py
from typing import Any

from main import transform, FixedClass, Desired


@transform()
def write_command(desired: Desired) -> None:
  return None


class Test(FixedClass):

  @transform()
  def read_command(self, desired: Desired) -> None:
    return None
```

I get pyright errors:

```
 /home/runner/MyPy-Test/test.py:6:2 - error: Argument of type "(desired: Desired) -> None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "(FixedClass, Desired, ...) -> Unknown"
    Type "(desired: Desired) -> None" cannot be assigned to type "(FixedClass, Desired, ...) -> Unknown"
      Function accepts too many positional parameters; expected 1 but received 2
        Parameter 1: type "FixedClass" cannot be assigned to type "Desired"
          "FixedClass" is incompatible with "Desired" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

```
  /home/runner/MyPy-Test/test.py:12:4 - error: Argument of type "(self: Self@Test, desired: Desired) -> None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "(Desired, ...) -> Unknown"
    Type "(self: Self@Test, desired: Desired) -> None" cannot be assigned to type "(Desired, ...) -> Unknown"
      Parameter 1: type "Desired" cannot be assigned to type "Self@Test"
        "Desired" is incompatible with "Test" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

```
  /home/runner/MyPy-Test/test.py:12:4 - error: Argument of type "(self: Self@Test, desired: Desired) -> None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "(FixedClass, Desired, ...) -> Unknown"
    Type "(self: Self@Test, desired: Desired) -> None" cannot be assigned to type "(FixedClass, Desired, ...) -> Unknown"
      Parameter 1: type "FixedClass" cannot be assigned to type "Self@Test"
        "FixedClass" is incompatible with "Test" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

For some reason is unable to match it to the correct argument type even though its a Union of both callables, so shouldn't either/or function/method be accepted?

and mypy errors:

```
test.py:6: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Desired], None]"; expected "Callable[[Desired, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], Any]"  [arg-type]
test.py:6: note: This is likely because "write_command" has named arguments: "desired". Consider marking them positional-only
```

```
test.py:6: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Desired], None]"; expected 
"Callable[[FixedClass, Desired, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], Any]"  [arg-type]
```

```
test.py:12: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Test, Desired], None]"; expected "Callable[[Desired, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], Any]"  [arg-type]

test.py:12: note: This is likely because "read_command of Test" has named arguments: "self". Consider marking them positional-only
```

```
test.py:12: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "Callable[[Test, Desired], None]"; expected "Callable[[FixedClass, Desired, VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], Any]"  [arg-type]

test.py:12: note: This is likely because "read_command of Test" has named arguments: "self", "desired". Consider marking them positional-only
Found 4 error
```

I tried searching why mypy cannot match it correctly, and why T isn't inferred (expected Any, rather than None), but was unable to reach an answer...

Comment: as an aside, you are using `inspect.ismethod` incorrectly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga treat it as an oracle, in my actual code I’m not using it but something similar I thought it would convey what I’m trying to show